# Box-Api : How to get the folder details of the co-admin user's account when trying to make an box-api calls of admin user's account?

Tags: box-api, box

I am using an Enterprise box account. I have created co-admin users & managed users. I can able to transfer files to admin account using tokens of admin user. How can I push files into co-admin's / managed user's account using box-java api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a new token logged in as the co-admin.  Then run the box-java code and it should work.

Comment: I am logged-in as an "Admin" user. And using the tokens of the same account. My target is to transfer files Managed User's account using BOX-JAVA-API.

Comment: You can create a folder and add those users as collaborators.

Comment: Thanks, that's one of the one way. But I am looking for - creating  folders & dropping files into Managed User's Account using tokens of Admin User's account. Any thoughts ?